# How to write a hyperledger composer function that requires two parties to confirm

Tags: function, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I want to construct a function in Hyperledger Composer that won't except a transaction until both parties confirm. For example, a supply chain transaction would not go through until the data comes in that says the shipment was fulfilled and then the supplier confirms that they got it. Is this possible in Hyperledger composer? Or Hyperledger fabric?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is possible in Composer, but I am not familiar with its mechanics. In Fabric, it is a simple chaincode endorsement policy. Example, AND(consumer.member, supplier.member); that is, the policy requires 2 signatures (1 from consumer and 1 from supplier). Obviously in order to sign the transaction proposal, both consumer and supplier make sure the smart contract (chaincode) satisfies the set condition: "the data comes in that says the shipment was fulfilled and then the supplier confirms that they got it." If either 1 or both signatures not valid, the transaction won't go through.